# Moodle audo quiz , audio player appears twice

Tags: moodle

I have created a quiz and added a question with an audio clip, following this procedure :

```
    Prepare your audio file in mp3 format on your machine.
Start editing your question the usual way.
text1
In this text the audio player will replace the word "put".

Select the word "put" putand press the link button.
When the insert window comes up locate the mp3 file on your computer, upload and choose it .
The "put" word will turn into a link. put2
You won't see the player here but don't panic.
You have to delete the "put" link. For this change the editor into HTML mode clicking on the html button.
And now this is the worst part if you don't write HTML code. Locate in the text in the link that consists of the word "put". It looks like this:

The player is <a title="mp3" href="http://ceptap.com/pictures/0000704.mp3"">put </a>here.

Delete the word "put". The rest is:

The player is here.

Go back to the normal editor window pressing again the <> button.
Your sentence now is:

The player is here.

It's really there but cannot be seen.
Finish your question, and close the editor window. Your question will look like this:

This is the question which consists of an audio file.
The player is here.
```

Audio Palyer works, but the player appears twice.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using poodll filter and poodll recording type question.Double filtering was happening because of poodll filter and multimedia filter.

I moved poodll filter up above multimedia filter, in the site administration > plugins > filters > manage filters.

This fixed the issue and i can view one audio player now.